# How can I get data from Django into R?

Tags: python, r, django

I have a Django-based application with an Oracle backend. I want to do analysis of the application's data in R. What can I do?

I would like to avoid directly querying the database because there are several aspects of our Django models that make it hard to understand the resulting database schema and would make the SQL very complicated.

I would also like to avoid writing a separate Python script to manually export data to a file and then load that file into R because these separate steps would slow down the analysis and iteration process.

My ideal would be some interface that would allow me to write Django queries directly in R. As far as I can tell the only option for this is [rPython](http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org/) and this would be tricky to set up with the necessary Django/Python environment variables et al (right?). Are there any other ways this direct interface could be possible?

I want to get the data into R because: 1) there are some statistical R packages that aren't well implemented in Python, 2) I am quicker at transforming data in R than Python, and 3) I need to plot the results and I find it easier to make ggplot2 plots look nice than matplotlib.

Comment: On django side develop some rest APIs using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ or https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. Then you can get data from the API into your R programs whenever you want to run the programs.

Comment: This still leads to slower iteration when I need to make changes to the query than what I was hoping for (Django queries directly in R) but this seems like it could be the best available route. It looks like [django-report-builder](https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder/) may also be a helpful addition to django-rest-framework for simpler data pulls.

Comment: There isn't much you can do when it comes to interactions of two different programs written in different languages besides using json/xml, etc to communicate. I'm not quite familiar with your domain knowledge, but just in case you haven't tried, python also got `numpy` and `pandas` like tools to do scientific calculations.